# PHP spits actual HTML instead of image

Tags: php, html

Having a small issue here but cannot figure out where I have gone wrong. I have the following code which should show an image depending on the condition but instead it shows the HTML in the browser

```
if ($this->id_status  == 2)
    {
            $this->id_status  = "<img src='../_lib/img/gray_dot.png' />";
    }
elseif ($this->id_status  == 1)
    {
            $this->id_status  = "<img src='../_lib/img/green_dot.png' />";
    }
elseif ($this->id_status  == 3)
    {
            $this->id_status  = "<img src='../_lib/img/orange_dot.png' />";
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you post the line where it is printed?

Comment: The error is not here, it's where you print it.

Comment: If you mean in the browser this is what it looks like: http://prntscr.com/7q6xq6

Comment: are you using some library to render the table ?

Comment: Here you can check the full code here: http://pastebin.com/nkTMbk6E it will expire in 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php

    if ($this->id_status  == 2)
        {
   ?>
<img src='../_lib/img/gray_dot.png' />
<?php
        }
    elseif ($this->id_status  == 1)
        {
?>
               <img src='../_lib/img/green_dot.png' />
<?php

        }
    elseif ($this->id_status  == 3)
        {
?>
<img src='../_lib/img/orange_dot.png' />
<?php

        }
?>
```

Comment: What is the error? If it syntax error please fix that one.